# index.php not working as default file in new directory

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, directory

I have looked at several other answers of the same question, yet none of the answers have actually worked.

What is happening, is when I try to create a new directory, and create a new file (index.php/index.html) then visit the directory (mydomain.com/newdirectory), it loads as a 404 page not found error.

This doesn't happen with my other directories. All the other ones load up just fine.

I have tried using a .htaccess file with **DirectoryIndex index.php** but no luck.

Sorry if this is one of hundreds of the same question.. I just couldn't find any that actually worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Sometimes for me Htaccess just takes a few minutes to update. Try waiting some and see if it works.

Comment: paste your error_log

Comment: GwiddleWorker I added the .htaccess file an hour ago. unixmiah There are no error logs.

Comment: You say it works fine for 'my other directories'. But you have the problem when you create new directories. May I ask how these other directories where created?

Comment: @FabianMiiro Same way as I created all my other ones. Using FileZilla and creating a new Directory.. Then Creating my new file. I can access the file by doing mydomain.com/mydirectory/index.php,  so I know the file works.

Comment: @Matt so no difference between the new files that doesn't work with index.php and the old ones that does?

Comment: check for common errors like index.HTML instead of index.html

Comment: @Matt Oki! Interesting, could you give some examples of folders working, and some not working. As well as .htaccess file of root folder?

Comment: @FabianMiiro I have a directory named Stats and another named profile, both work fine. This is my root Htaccess file: http://pastebin.com/f5hgkq87 (I have another htaccess file inside the directory with **DirectoryIndex index.html index.php** as well). The only non working directory is the newest one I made, which is called forums.

Comment: @anubhava Yes. I have tried **DirectoryIndex index.php** in the Htaccess file, but no luck.

Comment: OK can you show full code from /forums/.htaccess in your question.

Comment: @anubhava ... **DirectoryIndex index.php** is all that's in the Htaccess file.